# ¿Por qué razón mi diccionario es unhasheable? Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, lista, diccionarios, set

Tengo una lista que contiene los elementos (diccionarios) que el usuario decide ingresar del catálogo. El catálogo es el siguiente:

```
self.catalogo = [{"isbn": 0,"titulo": "Lluvia fina","precio": 33000},
{"isbn": 1,"titulo": "Amsterdam","precio": 40000},
{"isbn": 2,"titulo": "Seducción","precio": 80000},
{"isbn": 3,"titulo": "Obsesión","precio": 60000},
{"isbn": 4,"titulo": "Devoción","precio": 100000},
{"isbn": 5,"titulo": "Los renglones torcidos de Dios","precio": 50000},
{"isbn": 6,"titulo": "Plata quemada","precio": 20000},
{"isbn": 7,"titulo": "Intimidad","precio": 40000},
{"isbn": 8,"titulo": "Leonora","precio": 56000},
{"isbn": 9,"titulo": "Éramos unos niños","precio": 17000}]
```

Mi objetivo es obtener solo los elementos cuando no se repitan y dar una salida por pantalla de este tipo:

**En caso de que se haya seleccionado "Lluvia fina" dos veces:**

```
ISBN: 0 / Título: Lluvia fina / Precio: 33000 x2
```

Intente iterar sobre el set que genero con la función `set()`, ya que solo va a contener los diccionarios una vez (no-repetidos), e imprimir por pantalla ese "xN" con el método `count()` (obteniendo el número de veces que se repite un diccionario en la lista). Algo así:

```
for j in range(len(set(self.carrito))):
            print(f"ISBN: {set(self.carrito)[j]['isbn']} / Título: {set(self.carrito)[j]['titulo']} / Precio: {set(self.carrito)[j]['precio']} x{self.carrito.count(set(self.carrito)[j])}")
```

**Nota:** `self.carrito` está definido en el `__init__` de la clase (como lista vacía []), obtengo las elecciones del usuario así:

```
confirmacion = input("¿Desea añadir al carrito este libro? [Si o No]")
if confirmacion == "Si":
    cantidad = int(input("¿Cuantos desea añadir al carrito?"))

    for j in range(cantidad):
        self.carrito.append(libro)
```

Cuando ejecuto la iteración `for j in range(len(set(self.carrito))):`, obtengo este error:

```
  File "C:\Users\gabriel\Desktop\parteuno.py", line 78, in checkout
    for j in range(len(set(self.carrito))):
TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict
```

Nota: `self.carrito` es una lista que contiene diccionarios, estoy iterando en el rango de la longitud del set de este.

Ahí es donde surge mi pregunta: **¿Por qué se da este error, como pude solucionarlo o hay otra manera e conseguir lo que quiero?**

Investigando, me dí cuenta que un elemento unhasheable es uno inmutable. No tiene sentido que esté consiguiendo ese error , por que lo diccionarios se pueden modificar y las listas también. Además en ningún momento modifico en el set (ni siquiera itero directamente sobre el, si ¿no sobre el rango de su longitud)

**PD:**No adjunto todo el código, son 84 lineas, pero lo haré si es necesario.

Muchas gracias de antemano, un saludo!

Comment: Los diccionarios (dict) son unhasheables; no los puedes usar como argumento de un set(). Hay que pensar en otro metodo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se puede hacer en un solo bucle (mas o menos):

```
catalogo = [{"isbn": 0,"titulo": "Lluvia fina","precio": 33000},
{"isbn": 1,"titulo": "Amsterdam","precio": 40000},
{"isbn": 2,"titulo": "Seducción","precio": 80000},
{"isbn": 3,"titulo": "Obsesión","precio": 60000},
{"isbn": 4,"titulo": "Devoción","precio": 100000},
{"isbn": 5,"titulo": "Los renglones torcidos de Dios","precio": 50000},
{"isbn": 6,"titulo": "Plata quemada","precio": 20000},
{"isbn": 7,"titulo": "Intimidad","precio": 40000},
{"isbn": 8,"titulo": "Leonora","precio": 56000},
{"isbn": 9,"titulo": "Éramos unos niños","precio": 17000}]


carrito = [catalogo[1], catalogo[2], catalogo[0], catalogo[2]]

print(carrito)

carritofinal = []

for item in carrito:
    if item in carritofinal: # reviso si el diccionario esta en el carrito original
        item["cantidad"] += 1 # agrego 1 a la cantidad en el nuevo diccionario
    else:
        carritofinal.append(item) # Nuevo elemento lo agrego al nuevo diccionario
        item["cantidad"] = 1 # cantidad = 1 al ser un nuevo elemento

print(carritofinal)
```

Resultado:

```
[{'isbn': 1, 'titulo': 'Amsterdam', 'precio': 40000}, {'isbn': 2, 'titulo': 'Seducción', 'precio': 80000}, {'isbn': 0, 'titulo': 'Lluvia fina', 'precio': 33000}, {'isbn': 2, 'titulo': 'Seducción', 'precio': 80000}]
[{'isbn': 1, 'titulo': 'Amsterdam', 'precio': 40000, 'cantidad': 1}, {'isbn': 2, 'titulo': 'Seducción', 'precio': 80000, 'cantidad': 2}, {'isbn': 0, 'titulo': 'Lluvia fina', 'precio': 33000, 'cantidad': 1}]
```

Agrego la cantidad a los diccionarios

Comment: En efecto funciona, pero necesito iterar sobre el set o cualquier otra forma de no tener los datos repetidos. Esto último debido a que ocupo hacerle `print()` al elemento una sola vez y añadirle el "xN". Con to solución no puedo solventar que en el array de diccionarios hayan dos "valor2" o dos valores repetidos. De todos modos, muchas gracias por tu respuesta y tiempo.

Comment: Si estaba mirandolo :) he respondido muy rapido, modificaré mi respuesta sinó la borraré

Comment: He editado la respuesta para que se adapte mejor a lo que pedías. Espero que te ayude.

Comment: Creo que podrias hasta usarlo cuando el usuario agrega un elemento al carrito ... ni me habia dado cuenta :D

Answer (score 2):

Los diccionarions no son hasheables, asi que no se pueden poner en un set. Hay que buscar una manera más simple de lograr el resultado.

A partir del catalogo, llenamos el carrito con tres items (por ejemplo), uno de ellos repetido:

```
catalogo = [{"isbn": 0,"titulo": "Lluvia fina","precio": 33000},
{"isbn": 1,"titulo": "Amsterdam","precio": 40000},
{"isbn": 2,"titulo": "Seducción","precio": 80000},
{"isbn": 3,"titulo": "Obsesión","precio": 60000},
{"isbn": 4,"titulo": "Devoción","precio": 100000},
{"isbn": 5,"titulo": "Los renglones torcidos de Dios","precio": 50000},
{"isbn": 6,"titulo": "Plata quemada","precio": 20000},
{"isbn": 7,"titulo": "Intimidad","precio": 40000},
{"isbn": 8,"titulo": "Leonora","precio": 56000},
{"isbn": 9,"titulo": "Éramos unos niños","precio": 17000}]

carrito = [catalogo[0], catalogo[1], catalogo[0]]
```

Luego generamos un diccionario "salida" que cuenta las veces que aparece cada isbn (dado que el isbn puede contener guiones):

```
salida = {}
for item in carrito:
    isbn = item['isbn']
    if isbn in salida:
        salida[isbn] += 1
    else:
        salida[isbn] = 1
```

Finalmente, recorremos el carrito, recurriendo a "salida" para ver cuantas veces aparece cada ítem. Para evitar imprimir dos veces, ponemos la cuenta a cero después de la primera impresión:

```
for item in carrito:
    isbn = item['isbn']
    if salida[isbn] == 1:
        print (item)
    elif salida[isbn] > 1:
        print (item, salida[isbn])
        salida[isbn] = 0
```

Dando como resultado:

```
{'isbn': 0, 'titulo': 'Lluvia fina', 'precio': 33000} 2
{'isbn': 1, 'titulo': 'Amsterdam', 'precio': 40000}
```

Por supuesto, se puede mejorar, pero ahí está la idea básica

Comment: Entiendo la idea de tu algoritmo, pero no muestras cual es el valor de `isbn` (supongo que haces esa comparación dentro de un ciclo `for`), ademas comparas una llave del diccionario salida (que aparentemente esta vacío), en tu ejemplo no añades elementos a salida. Entones no entiendo con que estás comparando la llave "isbn" de cada diccionario del catálogo. De todos modos, muchas gracias por tu respuesta.

Comment: Gabriel: El diccionario "salida" se puebla con "salida[isbn] = 1". Copia el código y juega con él. Está completo y no falta agregarle nada.